Countif on time between two cells and value is "Y"
I would like to count the amount of Y's from "R3:AG3" if the time in row "2" is equal to or between the two times in "E3" and "F3".  In this instance the answer in "N3" would be 2 (the reds would be excluded and the greens would be included).  I have tried variations of countif without success.  Any support in a solution appreciated.


Try using MOD()+SUMPRODUCT() or SUM() functions combinations:


=SUM(
  (MOD(R2:AG2,1)>=MOD(E3,1))*
  (MOD(R2:AG2,1)<=MOD(F3,1))*
  (R3:AG3="Y"))


ONE NOTE: The above formula doesn't take the dates into account and only accounts for the times in between the start and end time, with an additional check to count the number of Ys in the range based on the given context in the OP.


Apologies, not sure I understand your "one note".  First part implies dates are not taken into account but second part implies it is based on date and time?

Hi @AlanTingey, the whole formula is based on time. Dates are not taken into account, see as per your screenshot the counts of 2 will only show when the times are taken and not the dates. The dates you have as start and end is 6/13/2024 while in the headers those are 6/12/2024. Hope I am able to explain?

The note is given like this: The above formula doesn't take the dates into account and only accounts for the times in between the start and end time, with an additional check to count the number of Ys in the range based on the given context in the OP and the one which you edited it includes dates which i have not mentioned.

Fully understand.  I suppose I was trying to make my example simpler and not include the date.  However, thinking about it in detail this will not be an issue for what I wish to use it for.
For purpose of interest would it be easy to amend to include the date?

Yes try using the COUNTIFS() that should work. If not let me know!

Its ok, just realised I need an amend to question but will create a new question.

@AlanTingey here is the COUNTIFS() function which you will need: =COUNTIFS(R2:AG2,">="&E3,R2:AG2,"<="&F3,R3:AG3,"Y") this will return you 2 considering both dates are same, the start+end and in headers

Many thanks, I will play with this and see if I can amend to fit into my question I have just posted here:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78627824/excel-countif-with-one-column-and-two-row-conditions

Thank I am updating it with an answer just had to draw the tables
