Excel: Countif with one column and two row conditions
In cell "N3" on the "Summary" worksheet I would like to return the number of Ys that meet the following conditions on the "breaks" worksheet:

Column A matches value in "J2" on "Summary Worksheet"
Time value in row 1 is equal to or between the values in "E3" and "F3" on the summary worksheet.
Row 2 contains a "Y"

I have visually shown in red that I wish to ignore the first two Ys as they are before the start time but include the second two Ys in green as they are equal or between E3 and F3 as mentioned above.
Have tried countifs and not quite got it resolved.  Any support on a resolution would be appreciated.
Summary Worksheet:

Breaks Worksheet:


The start and end time are 08:05 and 08:10 while in headers in breaks sheet the times starts from 08:00 but from the second column it shows as 21:01 onwards also the dates are different it will not give you the count of 2 the which you are looking for. Only if times are accounted then it would but still the times in headers are completely different please clarify more

Think that is where I have been amending it so much and half asleep.  Will amend the pictures now.

Images amended which should make the question make more sense.

Yes it does now!

Here is one way of accomplishing the desired output, this only needs the SUMPRODUCT() or SUM() function:


=SUMPRODUCT(
 (J3=Breaks!A$2:A$3)*
 (Breaks!B$2:L$3="Y")*
 (Breaks!B$1:L$1>=Summary!E3)*
 (Breaks!B$1:L$1<=Summary!F3))



@AlanTingey SUMPRODUCT() is simply easy and most incredible function. You just need to compare and do a matrix multiplication of the arrays. Also you can refer this link from ExcelJet will help you a lot. SUMPRODUCT by Dave & Lisa Bruns
